# Split dataframe into multiple output files

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have big dataset (but the following is small one for example). I can  split the dataframe and then I want to output to multiple text file corresponding to lavel used to split.

```
mydata <- data.frame (var1 = rep(c("k", "l", "c"), each = 5), var2 = rnorm(5), 
      var3 = rnorm(5))
mydata    
   var1       var2       var3
1     k  0.5406022  0.3654706
2     k -0.6356879 -0.9160001
3     k  0.2946240 -0.1072241
4     k -0.2609121  0.1036626
5     k  0.6206579  0.6111655
6     l  0.5406022  0.3654706
7     l -0.6356879 -0.9160001
8     l  0.2946240 -0.1072241
9     l -0.2609121  0.1036626
10    l  0.6206579  0.6111655
11    c  0.5406022  0.3654706
12    c -0.6356879 -0.9160001
13    c  0.2946240 -0.1072241
14    c -0.2609121  0.1036626
15    c  0.6206579  0.6111655
```

Now split

```
> spt1 <- split(mydata, mydata$var1) 

> spt1

$c
   var1       var2       var3
11    c  0.5406022  0.3654706
12    c -0.6356879 -0.9160001
13    c  0.2946240 -0.1072241
14    c -0.2609121  0.1036626
15    c  0.6206579  0.6111655

$k
  var1       var2       var3
1    k  0.5406022  0.3654706
2    k -0.6356879 -0.9160001
3    k  0.2946240 -0.1072241
4    k -0.2609121  0.1036626
5    k  0.6206579  0.6111655

$l
   var1       var2       var3
6     l  0.5406022  0.3654706
7     l -0.6356879 -0.9160001
8     l  0.2946240 -0.1072241
9     l -0.2609121  0.1036626
10    l  0.6206579  0.6111655
```

I want to write.table in name of `outputc`, `outputk`, and `outputl`. Thus output is common prefix followed by name of label for grouping variable.

```
write.table (spt1)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using lapply over the names of spt1 will allow us to access the dataframes in spt1 and the name that we can use in paste to create our files.

```
lapply(names(spt1), function(x){write.table(spt1[[x]], file = paste("output", x, sep = ""))})
```

You could add a common extension in the paste if you want.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use a really fast `data.table` solution. In this case, there is no need to split the `dataframe` into a `list`.

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.7 (devel version)

setDT(mydata) # convert your dataframe into a data.table

# save files
  mydata[, fwrite(.SD, paste0("output", var1,".csv")), by = var1]
```

In case you want to keep `var1` in the output, you can do this:

```
mydata[, fwrite(copy(.SD)[, var1 := var1], paste0("output", var1,".csv")), by = var1]
```

ps. note that this answer uses `fwrite`, which is still in the development version of `data.table`. [Go here for install instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). You could simply use `write.csv` or `write.table`, however you probably want a fast solution in case you're dealing with a big dataset and `fwrite` is certainly [one of the fastest alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505605/speeding-up-the-performance-of-write-table).

Comment: Maybe also worth noting: The OP wants to retain `var1` in the output but `.SD` does not contain it. You could try `c(.BY, .SD)` (not sure if that works) or use the new `split.data.table` method (currently in the devel version https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1389 )

Answer (score 0):

Joseph Flanagan has provided a [very elegant answer](https://gist.github.com/jflanaga/1ab2fa1434064780d2237e73d9e669c4) using tidyverse and `group_walk`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_walk(~ write_csv(.x, paste0(.y$Species, ".csv")))
```

Comment: Note: the grouping column itself is not exported! If you want to keep the grouping column, add `.keep=TRUE` before the last closing bracket.